# UITabBar custom color in WebView

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiwebview, uitabbar

Is there a way to customize the TabBar design in different views, cause I don't want my WebView to have the red color design, but rather a transparent design.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
struct TabView1: View {
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .red
    }
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ContentView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                    Text("Home")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put the same init in `ContentView`with another color or `nil` –  or set the color `.onAppear` and reset it `.onDisappear`

Comment: Both options didn't work either for me.